# Exchange 2010 Edge Server thinks it's inside the Exchange Organization, while it isn't

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange, subscription

I have a very strange problem with an Exchange 2010 Edge Transport Server.

The server was correctly subscribed to the Exchange Organization and worked, but then someone removed the subscription from the Hub Transport server. So I went to recreate it, starting by exporting the subscription file from the Edge server:

```
New-EdgeSubscription -FileName C:\EdgeSub.xml
```

And then I got this error:

```
New-EdgeSubscription : You can't use the FileName parameter when running this command inside your Exchange organization.
```

But this is an Edge server, and the Organization isn't talking to it anymore. And, of course, it isn't joined to any domain.

How can I force it to understand it's not part of any organization and recreate the subscription succesfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That server had some serious troubles, I went to uninstall Exchange and the installer crashed trying to do something that "can only be done on a Hub Transport Server". ***Why*** did it try to do that, then?

I ended up rebuilding it from scratch.

Still curious about what happened, though...